# Fitting a object on other object's surface

Tags: shrinkwrap

I attempted to get the object in second picture applied on a female body in third picture by using Shrinkwrap mode but it didn't work well and the object didn't fit well.
What should I do?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Align the two meshes in orthographic view , delete one side of the first mesh (the wireframe), add a mirror modifier, enter *Edit Mode*, enable *Proportional Editing*, and grab the chest part and other parts you wanna change and fit, apply the modifier, select both meshes, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>.

Since its a female and a male objects , you may need some light sculpting as well.